# foldRight on infinite lazy structure

Tags: scala, fold

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function), a right fold can operate on infinite lists if the full list does not have to be evaluated. This can be seen in action in haskell:

```hs
Prelude> take 5 (foldr (:) [] [1 ..])
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

This does not seem to work well in scala for streams:

```
Stream.from(1).foldRight(Stream.empty[Int])( (i, s) => i #:: s).take(5)
// StackOverflowError
```

or on iterators:

```
Iterator.from(1).foldRight(Iterator.empty: Iterator[Int]){ (i, it) => 
  Iterator.single(i) ++ it
}.take(5)
// OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Is there a practical solution to achieve a lazy fold right in Scala?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This article](http://voidmainargs.blogspot.com/2011/08/folding-stream-with-scala.html) makes the same observation, and suggests a lazy solution using scalaz.  Credit to the author, and Tony Morris.

Comment: Thank you. I can use scalaz. It works for `Stream`. Iterators seem more tricky...

Comment: The article doesn't suggest using scalaz at all, but gives a solution in pure scala which it says was inspired by scalaz's implementation: `def foldr[A, B]( combine: (A, =>B) => B, base: B )(xs: Stream[A]): B = if (xs.isEmpty) base else combine(xs.head, foldr(combine, base)(xs.tail))`