# Scala: Idiomatic way to generate a fixed length sequence (folding infinite stream?)

Tags: scala, stream, folding

Let's consider the problem of generating a sequence of random numbers, with the constraint that the final sequence should have a fixed length `n` and the preceding/subsequent elements should be different (i.e. neighbors should be different). My first idiomatic approach would be something like:

```
val seq = Stream.continually{ Random.nextInt(10) }
                .foldLeft(Stream[Int]()){ (all: Stream[Int], next: Int) =>
                  if (all.length > 0 && all.last != next)
                    all :+ next
                  else
                    all
                }
                .take(n)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, since the foldLeft tries to consume the whole infinite stream, resulting in an endless loop. Intuitively and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830471/foldright-on-infinite-lazy-structure) I would have expected this behavior only for solutions using `foldRight`? Maybe I'm just missing another idiomatic solution?

Comment: *the preceding/subsequent elements should be different* so there should be no repetitions for all sequence or only for neighbors?

Comment: Only neighbors should be different. The problem of unique elements would obviously require a completely different approach and would not even be solvable for arbitrary `n` / random number domains. Sorry for being imprecise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the trick with zipping a stream with itself:

```
def randSeq(n: Int): Stream[Int] = {
  // an infinite stream of random numbers
  val s = Stream.continually{ Random.nextInt(10) }
  s.zip(s.tail) // pair each number with it sucessor
   .filter((pair) => pair._1 != pair._2) // filter out equal pairs
   .map(_._1)   // break pairs again
   .take(n);    // take first n
}
```

Then you can filter out successive equal elements and finally take the desired amount.

**Update:** Yes, it will work. Suppose you have `[1,2,2,2,3,...]`. Zipping it will result in `[(1,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,3),(3,..),...]`, filtering produces `[(1,2),(2,3),(3,..),...]` so the final result is `[1,2,3,...]`.

We can even prove it: After pairing, the sequence has the following property: `a(i)._2 = a(i+1)._1`. This property is preserved in the filtering step. The filtering step also ensures that `a(i)._1 != a(i)._2`. Put together we get `a(i)._1 != a(i)._2 = a(i+1)._1` so indeed `a(i)._1 != a(i+1)._1`.

---

The problem with your approach using `fold` is that you're building the Stream bottom-up in your fold function. This means that in order to evaluate the head of the stream you have to evaluate an infinite sequence of `:+` operations, even though the head stays the same. A proper stream must be constructed top-down - compute its head and defer the computation of the rest in its tail. For example:

```
def randSeq1(n: Int): Stream[Int] = {
  def g(s: Stream[Int]): Stream[Int] =
    s match {
      case h #:: t => h #:: g(t.dropWhile(_ == h))
    }
  g(Stream.continually{ Random.nextInt(10) }).take(n);
}
```

Here we emit the head first and defer the rest of the computation to the lazily evaluated tail.

Comment: That is a nice trick; thanks for adding a stream based solution! Oh wait, does this really work? Because filtering out a pair can create a new conflict with the preceding neighbor?

Comment: Ok, it should work :). After all the preceding neighbor is always the same, even if we have a longer sequence of identical values. Guess I'm just a bit confused today...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked it yet, but I hope you will get the idea:

```
@annotation.tailrec 
def rndDistinctItems(n: Int, xs: List[Int] = Nil): List[Int] = if (n > 0) {
    val next = Random.nextInt(10)
    val shouldTryAgain = xs != Nil && next == xs.head
    if (shouldTryAgain) rndDistinctItems(n, xs)
    else rndDistinctItems(n - 1, next::xs)
} else xs
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, tail recursion is a very good alternative! Should probably be `xs: List[Int] = Nil` and `xs != Nil && ...`.

Answer (score 1):

While zipping the stream with its own head is a really nice trick, I prefer the `sliding` operator:

```
val s = Stream.continually { Random.nextInt(10) } sliding(2) collect { case Stream(a,b) if a!=b => a } take 100
```

**Beware:** You get an Iterator out of this, not a Stream. A Stream memorizes its result (and is therefor iterable multiple times). A iterator might be iterable only once.

Answer (score 1):

So, how about this:

```
scala> val M = 10
M: Int = 10

scala> val seq = Stream.iterate(Random.nextInt(M)){ x => 
         val nxt = Random.nextInt(M-1); if(nxt >= x) nxt + 1 else nxt 
       }
```

Comment: That's very clever. It took a few minutes to convince myself that the numbers would still be random. I suppose this particular solution is not very applicable to other cases though.